# Pyinstaller does not find files

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, pyinstaller, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to build an executable from a python script with sklearn. There are some warnings after pyinstaller name.spec like:

```sh
40983 WARNING: Hidden import "pysqlite2" not found!
40983 WARNING: Hidden import "MySQLdb" not found!
40984 WARNING: Hidden import "psycopg2" not found!
42337 WARNING: Hidden import "sqlalchemy.sql.functions.func" not found!
```

and some exclusions:

```sh
42344 INFO: Excluding import of sqlalchemy.testing.util from module sqlalchemy.orm.util
42345 INFO: Excluding import of sqlalchemy.testing.warnings from module sqlalchemy.testing
42345 INFO: Excluding import of sqlalchemy.testing.assertsql from module sqlalchemy.testing
42345 INFO: Excluding import of sqlalchemy.testing.util from module sqlalchemy.testing
42345 INFO: Excluding import of sqlalchemy.testing.exclusions from module sqlalchemy.testing
42345 INFO: Excluding import of sqlalchemy.testing.engines from module sqlalchemy.testing
42345 INFO: Excluding import of sqlalchemy.testing.config from module sqlalchemy.testing
42345 INFO: Excluding import of sqlalchemy.testing from module sqlalchemy.testing
42345 INFO: Excluding import of sqlalchemy.testing.mock from module sqlalchemy.testing
42345 INFO: Excluding import of sqlalchemy.testing.assertions from module sqlalchemy.testing
42345 INFO: Excluding import of sqlalchemy.testing from module sqlalchemy.testing.config
42345 INFO: Excluding import of sqlalchemy.testing from module sqlalchemy.testing.mock
42345 INFO: Excluding import of sqlalchemy.testing.assertsql from module sqlalchemy.testing.assertions
42345 INFO: Excluding import of sqlalchemy.testing.util from module sqlalchemy.testing.assertions
42345 INFO: Excluding import of sqlalchemy.testing.exclusions from module sqlalchemy.testing.assertions
42345 INFO: Excluding import of sqlalchemy.testing.config from module sqlalchemy.testing.assertions
42346 INFO: Excluding import of sqlalchemy.testing from module sqlalchemy.testing.assertions
42346 INFO: Excluding import of sqlalchemy.testing.mock from module sqlalchemy.testing.assertions
42346 INFO: Excluding import of sqlalchemy.testing from module sqlalchemy.testing.assertsql
42346 INFO: Excluding import of sqlalchemy.testing.engines from module sqlalchemy.testing.util
42346 INFO: Excluding import of sqlalchemy.testing from module sqlalchemy.testing.util
42346 INFO: Excluding import of sqlalchemy.testing.config from module sqlalchemy.testing.util
42346 INFO: Excluding import of sqlalchemy.testing.assertions from module sqlalchemy.testing.engines
42346 INFO: Excluding import of sqlalchemy.testing from module sqlalchemy.testing.engines
42346 INFO: Excluding import of sqlalchemy.testing.util from module sqlalchemy.testing.engines
42346 INFO: Excluding import of sqlalchemy.testing.config from module sqlalchemy.testing.engines
42347 INFO: Excluding import of sqlalchemy.testing from module sqlalchemy.testing.exclusions
42347 INFO: Excluding import of sqlalchemy.testing.config from module sqlalchemy.testing.exclusions
42347 INFO: Excluding import of sqlalchemy.testing from module sqlalchemy.testing.warnings
42347 INFO: Excluding import of sqlalchemy.testing.assertions from module sqlalchemy.testing.warnings
42347 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-multiprocessing.util.py' from '/home/grvc/ml/anaconda3/envs/rapids-0.17/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
42354 INFO: Excluding import of test.support from module multiprocessing.util
42354 INFO: Excluding import of test from module multiprocessing.util
```

And when executing it (`./dist/name/name`), I get errors when loading some modules:

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "online_sklearn_variable_depth.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 531, in exec_module
  File "sklearn/__init__.py", line 80, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 531, in exec_module
  File "sklearn/base.py", line 21, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 531, in exec_module
  File "sklearn/utils/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 531, in exec_module
  File "sklearn/utils/class_weight.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 531, in exec_module
  File "sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 25, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 531, in exec_module
  File "sklearn/utils/fixes.py", line 18, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 531, in exec_module
  File "scipy/stats/__init__.py", line 391, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 531, in exec_module
  File "scipy/stats/stats.py", line 174, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 531, in exec_module
  File "scipy/spatial/__init__.py", line 101, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 531, in exec_module
  File "scipy/spatial/_procrustes.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 531, in exec_module
  File "scipy/linalg/__init__.py", line 195, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 531, in exec_module
  File "scipy/linalg/misc.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 531, in exec_module
  File "scipy/linalg/blas.py", line 213, in <module>
ImportError: libcblas.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[13183] Failed to execute script online_sklearn_variable_depth
```

I have tried modifying the .spec file and adding hidden imports, but it does not help.

Dependencies of imports:

```sh
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os from sklearn.cluster 
import MiniBatchKMeans from sklearn.linear_model 
import SGDClassifier 
import time 
from functions.Cenangles import get_center_and_theta_proportional, Paint_lines, get_center_and_theta_threshold 
from realsense.camera_d400_v2 import Camera_D400 import fastcom.Publisher import fastcom.ImagePublisher 
import struct 
import signal
```

Where Cenangles only depends on cv2 and NumPy. Fastcomm depends on socket, sys, threading, PIL, io and array and realsense depends on pyrealsense2.

OS: Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Please can you provide more information about the script that you ran

Comment: Just edited question and added used imports